# Weak wireless connection in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 lts.

My wireless connection is very weak and every time I have to be very close to the wifi to be able to connect on the internet.

Should I type a specific command in the terminal?

**My router information:**

> MAC: F0-84-C9-7D-98-38
>   WLAN SSID: Wind Wifi 7D9838
>   S/N:ERDLD3T09861

**For the command in terminal : "lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net"** , the results are:

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:81fa]

Kernel driver in use: r8169

Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

DeviceName: Sanji2

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]

Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be

Kernel modules: rtl8723be

05:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900] (rev ff)

Comment: What make and model of computer and include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` Edit the question to include the info

Comment: I wrote the info